# Getting product variations on woocommerce 2.1

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I just upgraded from woocommerce 1.6 to 2.1. Now product options aren't posting to my hidden form.

I have this function built and have it in the cart.php template file of woocommerce. It's objective is to grab the product options/variances so that I can use it later in the hidden form.

```
$customs = array(); 
if (isset($values['variation'])) {
if (count($values['variation']) > 0) {
foreach ($values['variation'] as $property => $propertyValue) {
$customs[] = $property . ': ' . $propertyValue;
      }
   }
}
```

I then take that value and append into my hidden form, also found on cart.php

```
<input type="hidden" id="PRODUCT_CUSTOM_1_<?php echo $counter; ?>" name="PRODUCT_CUSTOM_1_<?php echo $counter; ?>" value="<?php echo implode(', ', $customs) ?>"/>
```

However, when I POST that form to a URL it doesn't have a value for the custom variable PRODUCT_CUSTOM. http://screencast.com/t/UiRJlCDciLYc All other variables contain a value.

Please help get this code to work in 2.1 like it did in 1.6 woocommerce.

Comment: have you checked your customs array before putting it to hidden field? try var_dump it first..

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, was on holiday. I have done the var_dump as suggested. I get back array(0) { } . So It is definately my custom array, but I am not sure what is wrong with it. It worked fine on 1.6

Comment: I just wrote out a array manually and it is posting over. Definately an issue with my custom array, but not sure what is wrong with it. I think it might be $propertyValue that is causing the issue.

Comment: umm check your $values array also if its empty you need to trace where it comes from.. that's how you debug.. I am sure its one of those variable name changes from v1.6 to v2.1

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Was on holiday. The variable never changed. It still is 'variation'. From my script, I can grab all the class values except for the product variation.